# I got this error(AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read') This program collects information from this site

Tags: python, web-scraping

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen("https://sis.ou.edu/ted/home/byOther?stat_code=ID&sbgi_code=004114&trns_subj_code=&trns_subj_crse=") as response:
   source=response.read()



data= json.load(source)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse Json from string use `json.loads` (note the `s` at the end). But the data received from `urlopen` is not in Json format (it's HTML page). To parse it, you can use for example `pandas.read_html`:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://sis.ou.edu/ted/home/byOther?stat_code=ID&sbgi_code=004114&trns_subj_code=&trns_subj_crse="
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    TransferSubject TransferCourse                  Transfer Title    TransferHours          TransferLevel Connector OU Subject  OU Course                        OU Title  OUCredits                       Gen. Ed.  Pass
0              ACCB            129     INTRODUCTION TO BOOKKEEPING                5         LOWER DIVISION       NaN        TRF       1999  LOWER DIVISION TRANSFER CREDIT          5                            NaN   NaN
1              ACCB            229       QUICKBOOKS PRO ACCOUNTING                5         LOWER DIVISION       NaN        TRF       1999  LOWER DIVISION TRANSFER CREDIT          5                            NaN   NaN
2              ACCT            201              PRIN OF ACCOUNTING                4  Lower Division Course       NaN       ACCT       2113   FUNDMNTL FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING          3                            NaN   NaN
3              ACCT            201              PRIN OF ACCOUNTING                4  Lower Division Course       AND       ACCT       1999  LOWER DIVISION TRANSFER CREDIT          1                            NaN   NaN
4              ACCT            202                PRINC OF ACCT II                4  Lower Division Course       NaN       ACCT       2123  FUNDMNTL MANAGERIAL ACCOUNTING          3                            NaN   NaN
5              ACCT            202                PRINC OF ACCT II                

...and so on.
```